Name for situation where "generated functions" become identical after a certain number of iterations?
Apologies if the term "generated function" is actually not what I mean to be asking about.
I am working on a physics/chemistry problem (not homework) where I have a "damping function" of the form.
\begin{equation}
f_n=1-e^{-r}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{r^k}{k!}
\end{equation}
This particular choice of function is quite common for the problem at hand. One can instead try to compute these damping functions from gradients of $g_1(r)/r$ where $r$ is the euclidean distance between two points. This generates different damping functions at various orders of the gradients.
I have noticed that for a particular choice of charge density which implies the form of $g_1(r)$ that the higher-order damping functions, $g_n(r)$ eventually become equal to $f_n(r)$ despite differing in the first few terms.
What gives rise to this situation where two sets of functions become equal only after a certain number of entries? Where can I read about this idea more broadly?
I am unfortunately not knowledgeable enough about this to know what the right words are. I think basically I am asking about two process that generate functions. Those two processes begin giving identical functions after a certain number of iterations of the process. I would like to read about what properties such processes might have. Any recommended topics to read about are welcome.
